# Can I do Bitcoin minning on Linux without a graphic card?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bitcoin

I just upgraded my Linux Ubuntu to 13.04 and my graphic card is not supported yet (I think is a Intel HD Graphics 4000).

I'm looking for a Bitcoin minner but I'm not sure if I can mine it before setting up my graphic card.

Can I? And if yes, what minner/configuration should I use?

Comment: Try bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you have almost 0% of chances of getting any bitcoins!

Please see this calculator:

http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/

Comment: Even if I join a Bitcoin Minning Pool, like TripleMinning?

Comment: Well, technically speaking you might be "lucky" and get some bitcoins. In reality you will spend more money on electricity then it's worth. With your power (even with a one GPU) you are wasting your time and money.